# Is this silverlight bug or I am doing something wrong? Grid alignment

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have one grid that has 14 columns. If I place another grid of 28 columns in first column of first grid and span it by 14 it split every column on two parts. But if I create grid of 42 columns(3x14) it doesn't split every column on three eaqul parts.

This one works:
[image]

This doesn't work (not equally split):
[image]

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
Width="640" Height="480">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid x:Name="AllWhiteKeys" Margin="0,0,0,200">         
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Name="WhiteKey1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8"/>
        <Rectangle Name="WhiteKey2" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="1" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8"/>
        <Rectangle Name="WhiteKey3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="2" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8"/>
        <Rectangle Name="WhiteKey4" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="3" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8"/>
        <Rectangle Name="WhiteKey5" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="4" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8"/>
        <Rectangle Name="WhiteKey6" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="5" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8"/>
        <Rectangle Name="WhiteKey7" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="6" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8"/>
        <Rectangle Name="WhiteKey8" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="7" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8"/>
        <Rectangle Name="WhiteKey9" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="8" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8"/>
        <Rectangle Name="WhiteKey10" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="9" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8"/>
        <Rectangle Name="WhiteKey11" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="10" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8"/>
        <Rectangle Name="WhiteKey12" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="11" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8"/>
        <Rectangle Name="WhiteKey13" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="12" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8"/>
        <Rectangle Name="WhiteKey14" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="13" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8"/>

        <Grid Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="14">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>

                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>

                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simply a rounding error.

Your total width is 640, divided into 42 columns is 15.23 pixels each, but the columns round to the nearest pixel as they count across, so the columns creep back and forth slightly.

If you change the design width to a multiple of 42 (e.g. 630) it goes away. See sample below (630 * 480):

[image]

As @Joe White mentions you can turn off the rounding using `UseLayoutRounding`, but as you want it to be crisp and clear you need to start thinking pixel-based dimensions (like the good days of early video game development).

Answer (score 0):

As @HiTechMagic said, this is most likely a rounding error. By default, Silverlight rounds all positions to the nearest integer.

If you want things to line up exactly, you can set [`UseLayoutRounding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.uselayoutrounding%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to False on your outer `Grid`.

If you do this, be aware that some things will be at fractional-pixel positions, so images will look blurry and backgrounds won't match up seamlessly (which is probably why layout rounding is on by default). If you're trying to make a piano keyboard, though, you'll probably be fine -- the only elements with backgrounds would be the black keys, and no two of those are ever adjacent.